# Cannot Fetch GPS Coordinates Through LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gps

I cannot fetch the location using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`. But it is working with `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

```
val locationManager=getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,500, 100F,listener)//It's working if i use NETWORK_PROVIDER

val listener=object :LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        latitude = location!!.latitude.toString()
        longitude = location!!.longitude.toString()

        Log.d("location", "$latitude $longitude")
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
    }

    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a reference of this repo : https://github.com/yash786agg/GPS

Comment: Go outside. GPS won't work indoors.

Comment: Have you add fine location permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes , i have added fine location in my manifest file.

Comment: Adding to manifest isn't enough if targeting modern Android versions. A runtime permission for "fine location" is needed.

Comment: Agree with @MarkusKauppinen, I recommend you, use `GPS Essentials` application available on google play, so you can see either there is any satellites available or not. usually there is no satellite available indoors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Solutions:
1. Maybe your GPS location is switched off in your mobile device. So try to switch it ON and check location.
2. Try to implement [**Fused location provider**](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/) which is provided by Google Play Services API as it improves performance, saves battery life and provides more accurate location

Comment: Highfive For introducing the `FusedLocationProvider`